# CSS3 webkit fading in a tooltip

Tags: css, css-transitions

I've just been experimenting with a CSS tooltip that fades in with CSS3's transitions. I was going for a tooltip effect that when you hover a link, the tooltip appears, but fades in using only CSS3.

I've got it working up to a point, but for some reason, when I hover over where it's meant to be, it activates, even though it's initally positioned `left:-999px;`.

So basically, what am I doing wrong/is what I was going for possible? (Note I don't want to do anything with JS/JQuery, was just curious to see if I could do it in CSS)

You can see and play with it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4EmwY/).

Comment: can you please explain what exactly is the expected behavior, and what is the behavior that is actually happening? I don't really understand the problem :(

Comment: Updated, hope that's better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `span` is still in the `document` flow.

You can remove it by setting its `display` to `none`, as the comment above suggests, or setting its `position` to `absolute`, which seems to be what you were getting at to hide it off the left edge of the screen.

Comment: Position:absolute; is the way to do it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the tool tip to not even be shown normally.

```
#one a.tooltip span {
//display:block;
display:none; 
....
}
```

Edit: It seem that rather then set display to none, just position to absolute.
Edit2: it seems I was beaten to it.

Comment: I like the way that works out. "Your slow... have some rep!" I could get along quite happily like this :D ... now, how can I make money from rep?

Comment: Now making money out of it would be one hell of an achievement!